# How to set different \clubpenalty for main text and footnotes?

Tags: memoir, widows-orphans

I am using `memoir` class to typeset a book containing texts with many footnotes. To control widows and orphans I use the following settings:

```
\clubpenalty=5000
\widowpenalty=5002
\displaywidowpenalty=5000
\brokenpenalty=2991
```

Generally I am satisfied with the result. But with this settings LaTeX tries hard to avoid widows and orphans and sometimes it has to break a page just to avoid an orphan in the footnotes resulting in huge white zones at the bottom of the page.
As I sometimes rather had some orphans in footnotes – I suppose them to be much more tolerable there, then in the main text – then huge white zones at the bottom of some pages, I would like to set a lover `\clubpenalty` for the footnotes.

I read about the `bigfoot` package providing such functionality, but as I have some trouble with it, I would like to know, if there is an other way to achieve that?

Comment: Can you show is some code that replicates your current behaviour? It would lay a solid foundation from where possible solutions may start.

Comment: Are you using `\flushbottom`, `\feetatbottom` or any other related settings?